# Loss of wireless connection on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a HP laptop and I get a system error on start up, after an update.

I ran system check which shows this error:

```
Fontconfig warning:ignoring C.UTF-8 not valid language tag
```

I do not have any wireless icon in the top right-hand corner, while the Bluetooth icon is still showing. I tried to hard wire to the router but no joy.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Yes, I also had this problem - http://askubuntu.com/questions/773924/network-manager-crash-not-resolved - but this fox worked like a charm. Excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend called me yesterday for the same reason. I'll give you a brief outline on your issue:

- the core network functionality of your Ubuntu system is **not** broken
- however, the GUI functionality **is** broken
- this means you can still connect using the command line and fix the problem

Here's what you need to do. First of all, connect the laptop to your router using an ethernet cable. Then open the *Terminal* and ensure the wired interface is up by running:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> afterwards, then run `ifconfig`. You should see something similar to:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr **:**:**:**:**:**  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0

[...]
```

`eth0` is the name of your wired network interface. Assuming the router has a working DHCP functionality, you can get an IP address with:

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Open your browser and confirm you can surf the web. Now it's time to check for system updates and install them:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Reboot the system and your Wi-Fi connection should be up and running again.

Comment: Done and get eth0up; error fetching interface information: Device not found.Not sure how to update question? Doing this on my mac. thanks

Comment: ISSUE RESOLVED using "sudo ifconfig eth0 up before ifconfig" method on 4th attempt. How do I thank you? (I'm new) Andrea Lazzaretto. Is now the time to upgrade to 16.04? Many thanks Doug ;-)

Comment: I was asking you to [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/772646/edit) your question, however it is not necessary anymore since you solved it. To thank for a solution you just need to upvote useful answers and accept the one you believe it is the best (I see you already did it, hence you are done!). I will now go on and update my answer to reflect the additional command I provided in the comment and I will flag my comment as obsolete. When you will have enough rep, you will be able to edit any question or answer to improve it.