# Unable to connect to the internet, Network menu has disappeared

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, menu

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Lenovo Think-pad laptop some months ago.
Everything has been working fine until yesterday. Don't know whether something hasn't updated correctly. Very new to Ubuntu and non-technical. Tried following thread for this problem by following instructions:

**Open Terminal**

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Pressed `enter` and received message that not all "information" could be recovered from archives, or something like that continued with the following instructions in *Terminal*:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop  
sudo apt-get install unity  
sudo shutdown -r now
```

After shutting down I restarted, but the network menu was still not there.
Then I followed instructions in Ubuntu help to get error messages from *Terminal* as follows:

> **(nm-applet:2379): WARNING**: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
>
> **(nm-applet2379): nm-applet-WARNING**: Error connecting to ModemManager: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Modem-Manager1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Cannot launch daemon,file not found or permission invalid
>
> **(nm-applet:2379): nm-applet-WARNING**: Could not find ShellVersion property on org.gnome.Shell after 5 tries
>
> **(nm-applet:2379): nm-applet-WARNING**: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files

Similar error messages were also generated in the *Terminal* before I tried the troubleshooting steps found in the thread but the `nm-applet` number was 2867, not 2379.

I only have Ubuntu installed on my Lenovo laptop but also run a separate laptop with MS Windows with no internet connection issues, so I know there is not problem with my Wifi.

Comment: Check out the answer I gave here: http://askubuntu.com/a/772695/271

Comment: Before you do anything with a repository, like `apt-get install`, always do `apt-get update`  to update the list of packages.

Comment: Check out the answer I gave here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/772317/network-manager-crashes/772324

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once and by changing `nm-applet` to launch with `dbus-launch nm-applet` solved my problem. To see if this will work for you, run in terminal

`dbus-launch nm-applet`

and see if network menu shows up. If menu shows than to make the fix permanent, edit

`/etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop`

and change

```
Exec=nm-applet
```

to

```
Exec=dbus-launch nm-applet
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a regression resulting network-manager not to be able to start. Here is the procedure to fix it (as this has already been fixed with an update):

1. revert to an previous version
2. start network service again
3. Install the latest updates

**Revert to an older version**

Open your terminal and issue the following

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-200=3.2.21-1 libnl-route-3-200=3.2.21-1 libnl-genl-3-200=3.2.21-1
```

Note: if for some reason, the packages are not in the cache folder, you will need to download them from another computer:

- Download links for amd64: [libnl](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb) [libnl-genl](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb) [libnl-route](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb)
- Download links for i386: [libnl](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu3_i386.deb) [libnl-genl](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu3_i386.deb) [libnl-route](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1ubuntu3_i386.deb)

Then open a terminal in the folder where you saved them and install them with

```
sudo dpkg -i libnl-*.deb
```

**Start Network Service**

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

Then you will be automatically connected to the internet

[Reverting to an older version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZoV9.png)

**Install the latest updates**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

As you can see from the following changlog, this has been fixed and you can safely update

[image]